Why Everyone Should Help in the Sandbox
This post exists because SE no longer has community advertising. I expect the post to be closed and removed, but I hope a bunch of people will see it first.
What is the Sandbox?
The Sandbox is a page in Worldbuilding Meta where people can test their questions before putting them on Main. The goal of the poster is to avoid question closure. The goal of you, potential participant, is to help people learn how to ask good questions.
Why should I help?
Stack Exchange's rules were originally designed for people like engineers and programmers who need help overcoming specific problems in ways where an objective best answer is important. Worldbuilding is the most creative stack in the SE universe — but all those rules still exist. Helping people understand how to work with the rules to make the most of their experience here is incredibly valuable.
How do I help?
Visit the Sandbox, scroll down to an "answer" (potential questions are "answers" to the Sandbox "question"), read it, then post comments about how to improve it or whether or not you think it's suitable. Pointing out rules and policies the OP should be aware of is valuable. The Sandbox is a place for guidance about how to ask questions, it is not a place to get answers to questions.
If everyone visited the Sandbox once a month to help review just one question, it would improve the sandbox by about four orders of magnitude.
Why did you post this?
The Sandbox is listed in the Help Center, but few people bother reading the Help Center pages and even fewer do so regularly. As a result, most users don't think about the Sandbox much.
Thanks for reading this!

It's simple, really - this is not a worldbuilding question. It's about Worldbuilding.SE - it should be on Meta. And even though there is no community advertising, meta questions with a good enough score positive score (cat least 3) will show up as "Hot Meta Questions" in the sidebar on the right everywhere on main site. Hot meta questions are visible for two weeks. Also, meta posts can be featured by moderators and would show up in the side bar as well.

@VLAZ No, it's not simple. Moving this to Meta was a foolish choice. Almost no one visits Meta anymore and those lists to the right on Main are a forest of ignored nonsense (the fact that Meta is so infrequently visited attests to this), so it's preaching to an empty room. Without some way of advertising the Sandbox actively (rather than passively in the [help]) it gets very little attention. At least it had 50+ views before consignment to the depths.

¯\(ツ)/¯ it's not a topic for Main. I don't think that's something that should elicit disbelief.

It shows up normally in featured news...

@JBH It actually still shows up in main as a migrated post, and links here, so mission most accomplished?

@VLAZ To help the community itself, some rules can be bend, surely? Lots of stacks have their own quirks that go against standard SE regulations, that are there for guidance and to serve a greater purpose to begin with. If it shoots itself in the foot otherwise..
